# Suppress session_start() Warnings (headers already sent)

Tags: php, session, download

I have a situation where I need to call `session_start()` in the middle of the file multiple times. Obviously, as `session_start()` outputs buffer, I get the following warnings:

- `Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by...`
- `Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent...`

There was a lot of written on StackOverflow about header related warnings caused by `session_start()`. Now before you decide to mark this post as a duplicate, please continue reading - you will see, it is different.

Most of the proposed solutions in the other threads recommend putting `session_start()` at the beginning of the file, before any PHP output is made. This can be suitable solution if `session_start()` needs to be called only once per file - however, it is not my case.

I have a file download script (see the code below.) My script regularly, during the file download, updates '$_SESSION' variables with download progress status. I have then another script regularly issued through AJAX requests, which monitors download progress and informs my JavaScript code.

To avoid locking the `$_SESSION` variables, I therefore have to call `session_start()` and `session_write_close()` multiple times per file download, which occurs in a loop in the PHP file.

As every subsequent call to `session_start()` returns the warnings, which in my case are injected into the downloaded file, is there any programmatically correct way of suppressing them?

Two solutions come to my mind now, but I am not happy with none of them:

1. calling `@session_start()` instead of `session_start()` - this is not considered as a good practice, as it suppresses all warnings and errors returned by the function.
2. calling `ob_clean()` to empty the output buffer at the end of every file write iteration, to remove the warnings injected into the buffer to be written to the file. - in this case, the warnings are still present, I do not correctly manage the situation, I simply erase the warning and ignore it.

So my question, please, how to correctly call `session_start()` and `session_write_close()` multiple times per file and avoid getting warnings?

### Code Sample:

```
<?php    

//...    


// file download in small pieces
while(!feof($file_source))
{
    $chunk_data = fread($file_source, $chunk_size);
    print($chunk_data);
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    $bytes_already_transferred += strlen($chunk_data);
    $percent_complete = round(($bytes_already_transferred / $file_size) * 100);

    // update session variable, but how to avoid warnings?
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();
    $_SESSION['DownloadProgress'] = $percent_complete;
    session_write_close();

    usleep(1000);
}

fclose($file_source);
?>
```

Comment: your situation is like any other. DO NOT DO OUTPUT. If you cannot avoid output, then use output buffering. If you cannot use output buffering, then don't use sessions.

Comment: Marc B, it is not possible not to output 4GB file and store it all in server buffer. Which means, I am here to ask if there is a practical solution for my case.

Comment: Why don't you just start a session before the cycle and close if after? Why should starting a session be inside?

Comment: Use a different communication scheme. Use `session_start` at the beginning and `session_write_close` it, then use a session id to read/write into a database table (or a file on disk, whatever) where you communicate the progress.

Comment: @ArtjomKurapov, hi and thanks for response. Imagine, the user downloads a file that is 500MB large. It will take him 15 minutes to download. I have progress monitoring information with estimated time needed, etc.. I get this information by regularly scanning `$_SESSION['DownloadProgress']` from another script. I have to close session in one file, before I access `$_SESSION['DownloadProgress']` from another. So to have the session variables available, I have to regularly close the session. To modify the variable, I have to start the session.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, hallo.. Is this unnecessary overkill for the application, when I have to access the database every second, or update disk file every second? I have already consideder, I hope, there is a solution with sessions for me, which I am not yet aware of.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori perhaps you could use a way of communicating through memory. Note that session variables are also written to disk, so basically you are doing it already. That, and any OS will buffer those writes, they will probably never hit the disk at all.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori but why are you implementing things in PHP/JavaScript that ought to be (and already are!) implemented in the browser?

Comment: @BartFriederichs - I take advantage of the browser download. However, browser provides only limited information. It is basically, because I want to have things in my way, but still correct.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, ah so there is not much advantage between storing session variables and manually outputting to disk. I did not know that. Lets see what others put here. Maybe somebody will have good idea, to take advantage of memory only - kind of global variables, but not session.

Comment: Your progress meter is useless anyways. All you're counting is how much data has been sent to the webserver's output buffer. it is **NOT** an indication of how much data has actually gone out onto the wire and actually arrived at the client side.

Comment: Marc B, what one finds useless the other finds beneficial. I am not implementing it on your portal, but on my one. And I am not asking you to reuse my code, neither this question sounds "Is my progress meter useful?" I hope this answers your point.

Comment: Using `ob_clean()` stops the warnings from appearing in your output but they will still appear in your error log. Using `@start_session()` will prevent both, although I agree with you that `@` should be avoided wherever possible.